# What is the imagePickerController delegate method before the didfinishpickingmediawithinfo method is called?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

So I have a visual cue (PNG rectangle lines) that pops up when taking a picture for this test app I’m doing.

So I remove the visual cue in the did finish picking media delegate method and/or the didcancel method as well. But I can’t find info on a delegate method for inbetween. Is there one? If there isn’t, is there a way to handle using a visual cue during image taking but not during the deciding “phase”?

I've looked at the Apple Docs but can't find anything so far. I'm trying to be better as far as attention to detail but I still struggle so my apologies if I didn't see it

I don't think there's code necessary to show so I can't show sample code.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only delegate methods are `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` and `imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_:)`.

If you want to customize the user interface during picture taking, you can take a few approaches.

First, use [the `cameraOverlayView` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619113-cameraoverlayview) to customize the UI.

Second, note that the `UIImagePickerController` is itself a `UINavigationController`. You can therefore set its [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621876-delegate) and respond to `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` to be notified when the user is about to move between view controllers. You could implement logic here to show, hide, or otherwise adjust your custom UI.

Comment: Awesome thanks Aaron. That totally makes sense. I'm stepping away from the coding until tomorrow so i'm signing off but this totally makes sense so i'll get on it tomorrow and once i'm finished i'll come back and give you the check mark and then comment the way I did it!

Comment: Hi Aaron, sorry i've had kind of a busy day D: so only getting to this now.

So I was already using the cameraoverlayview property to customize the UI which is how I have the visual cue. 

The problem is i'm not sure how to remove it after the picture has been taken but retake/usephoto hasn't been clicked. I used the willShow and it's only called (twice) once I initiate the imagepicker but never again. So it's not called after I take a picture. Will look more into the navigationcontroller methods though :D